# Count number of times the value differs for all columns and for a same id

Tags: sql

So here is my problem :

I have tons of doublons in my data, and I would like to count in SQL the number of times a column doesn't have the same value for a same id.

So, for example, if I have the following table :

[image]

Here is the output I would like :

Name : 2

Email : 3

Age : 1

State : 5

Could someone please help me?

Keep in mind I have a lot more columns in my real data, so doing it one by one is not the best solution. I would like a code which can count it for all columns directly, but for the moment I didn't find a solution :/

Thank you, and take care of you!

Comment: *I have a lot more variables in my real data* - there are no variables in your question, or for that matter any code at all; did you mean to say *columns*?

Comment: @Stu oh yeh you're right sorry, I mean to say columns. I've just corriged it. Thank you

Comment: Any solution you apply to a single column you would have to repeat for each additional column - this is assuming your RDBMS is a traditional row-store and not column-store.

Comment: oh alright I see then I'll repeat the solution for each additional column... But I still can't find the solution for one column also ^^'

Comment: A possible solution would be to use aggregation and counting. If you were to include actual sample data that's not an image & TAG your RDBMS someone might be willing to assist.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. I've tried it but I didn't find a way to include actual sample data so I've send an image... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for a specific column could look like:

```
select distinct Count(*) over()
from t
group by id
having Count(distinct name) > 1;
```

**Result: 2**

```
select distinct Count(*) over()
from t
group by id
having Count(distinct age) > 1;
```

**Result: 1**

If you can make use of *window functions* an example of counting multiple columns in a single query would be:

```
select 
    Count(distinct case when name1 != name2 then id end) NameCount, 
    Count(distinct case when age1 != age2 then id end) AgeCount
from (
    select *,
      Min(name) over(partition by id) name1,
      Max(name) over(partition by id) name2,
      Min(age)  over(partition by id) age1,
      Max(age)  over(partition by id) age2
    from t
)t;
```